# Updating or Deleting Ephemeral Message After Clicking Interactive Button

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

Current Scenario: A user is sent an ephemeral message with 2 interactive buttons, 'Yes' and 'No', from my slack app.

What needs to happen: When the user clicks on 'Yes', the message should be updated to no longer be ephemeral and instead be visible in the channel. I was thinking of deleting the message with *chat.delete* and then sending a new message with *chat.postmessage* to the channel which basically is the same as before but is not ephemeral.

When the user clicks on 'No', the message should be updated to no longer have the attachment for the 2 interactive buttons and remain ephemeral but have the other content.

What I've tried: I've tried using chat.delete on the **message_ts** from the payload when clicking the button but that did not delete the message. From the other stack overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455540/slack-api-chat-update-message-not-found), it seems we should use the **response_url** and send a HTTP post request. However, I'm still unclear as to how we "update" the message.